# Adding item to startup script, and running as certain user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, startup

How do I add an item to the startup sequence of linux. I would like it to be the /last/ thing to load, and I would like it to run as a certain user, how would I achieve this?

Comment: This is not a programming question and better suited for unix.so. This is also distro dependent since sysvinit is no longer universal, and the tools for configuring sysvinit never were.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's allowed to link to other sites here, but I found this tutorial to be very useful. It's concerning all the major distros, which you didn't specifyed.

https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts

Try giving us more information about your system.